# Login prompt for SharePoint Home page for one of the language

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, language-pack

I have a front end server where I am getting login prompt when I access the home page. The weird thing in my SharePoint 2010 site is that it is configured with two languages like English and German, but the login prompt is coming only for one language.

I do not understand what configuration dependency is there for one of the language that, its happening only for one of the language and not work for other?

If anyone has come across this kind of issue and have any suggestion, Please advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting a login prompt for a particular page - regardless of which language - it could be due to some files NOT being checked-in + published.

This could be JPG, CSS, or Master Page, Page Layout - or - if the user has put some images in a content editor - and the user needs to AUTH to the page.

Language variations within SharePoint will have different files (behind the scenes) - I'd check to see if any of those are checked out.

Comment: How to find which image or content is checked-out..there are so many files on home page

Comment: You could look at the page using FIDDLER - and see which one has a 401 - or via the IE Dev ToolBar.   Often tricky to work out !

Comment: Otherwise, look at the page as "Admin" - and see what files are showing - check your SiteAssets for JS, CSS and JPG files

Comment: I couldnt find any check out files images or anything on the page. So i removed the webparts and once I removed all the prompt stopped coming. I re-added them and still no prompts. The issue has been fixed now but the cuse of it is still unclear. Anyhow...may be some other day..thanks all for the help.

Comment: @Ankit: That is exactly what I suggested to do for troubleshooting. Shame you didn't mark my answer.

Comment: First the root cause of the issue was not identified. It was just that re-adding of webparts fixed the issue..and second there was no response from you  after my last comment...just for the sake I have to award 50 bounty i awarded the one to whom I was talking... Save the Shame part...and Grow Up!!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have something being loaded on the homepage which triggers login otherwise for a public site you won't expect a login page (which also explains why no login is presented when you view site contents page). Please compare the assets loaded on the homepage between different languages. You can use fiddler or developer toolbar of your browser (chrome works nice, use F12 to open the developer tool and checkout the network tab for 401 return code) and see which request is resulting in unauthorized response (401).

Comment: There is no error logged in console tab for the other language. The assests loaded are same in both the languages.

Comment: Have you checked the network tab of developer tools? Please also check "Preserve log" option to keep items in the list in case you are redirected to another page for login. If it's only one page requesting the login then it is most likely related to something on that page.

Comment: what am i suppose to look in the network tab

Comment: In the network tab you see a table with columns. On e of the columns is called Status. Check whether you can find a row with status 401. Make sure you are recording otherwise no table will be shown. Here is some info about the network tab: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/profile/network-performance/resource-loading

Comment: yes i get one row where URL is  en/Pages with status as 401. What can be done now.

Comment: But that is the url of my page which is throwing error i.e. xxxx.com/en/Pages/default.aspx

Comment: I would first check the page level permissions and whether the page is published. If permissions are OK and it is published you should try to remove all webparts from the page and see whether that helps. If the page is still throwing 401 after removing the webparts you could check there are other 'things' on the page requesting info from other data sources (list, libraries) like scripts for example. It's hard to give troubleshooting tips without knowing environment.

Comment: Well its a home page and I do have webparts associated on that page along with other things on the page requesting data from other sources.

Comment: Ok..One thing I have noticed during my troubleshooting...when I hit the url".../sites/en/Pages" it gives an error as Access Denied. Same thing in my staging server for my staging site, url".../sites/en/Pages" redirect me to".../sites/en/Pages/default.aspx" and my staging server works fine for any language. I think this is the issue.So from where can I change this? How can I redirect the url to "../Pages/default.aspx"

Comment: And this is what i get in developer tool in Network tab in Response body:


 <html dir="ltr"> <HEAD> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" name="CharsetDefinition"> </HEAD><body ID=idErr><p><H2>Access denied.</H2></p> <p>You do not have permission to perform this action or access this resource.</p> <!-- commentElt Access denied. --></body></html>





Is it some kind of content type error??

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but the prompt will work with your site locale.

Try:

```
$web =Get-SpWeb <your url>
$web.Locale
```

And see if that can give you an answer.

Comment: Dont have powershell in the production server

Answer (score 0):

You have to create custom login page for your SharePoint 2010 windows authentication.

You can get the reference from the below mentioned link.

[Creating a Custom Login Page for Windows Authentication](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/chunliu/2010/09/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication/)

You have to pass the parameter (as querystring) on the custom login page for language like `lng=en` OR `lng=ger`.

When user is going to open the page using the URL then you need to identify the language from the querystring & change the text according to language.

You can check below link to understand how multilingual SharePoint 2010 sites work.

[Supported and unsupported language settings](http://sharepoint-tutorial.net/post/2011/06/08/sharepoint-language-settings-and-regional-settings.aspx)

**UPDATED**

**NOTE :-** When a user selects a different language, that choice will be remembered for future visits. There is however no option to make the call the any page in SharePoint without coding in other language.

Comment: why login page again..this was working before...The login prompt started just few days back for one of the language

Comment: Is that your custom login page on which you want multilingual controls?

Comment: its a public facing site and the prompt is IE prompt for a SharePoint Home Page

Comment: Its not happening for other pages in the site..its happening only for one page that also for only one language

Comment: Login page works before you login to your site. so it is an obvious behaviour.

Comment: ok..i am not getting something. I have a SharePoint site... if I go to the home page of the site, login prompts comes for one particular language...but when I close the browser and open _layouts/viewlsts.aspx...i dont get any prompt for any of the language..

Comment: can you share me a screen capture? so i can understand it better

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure, but the language of your login page should be following the language of your browser/windows box.

Try using IE after setting the preferred language:

Internet Options > General > Languages > Add your language and put it at the top.

(All this provided that the alternative languages have been set here: 
http://yoursite/_layouts/15/muisetng.aspx)